# Executing script in Background

Tags: powershell, jobs

I have a requirement to run a background script from main script,

Main script:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    C:\Temp\EMEAProductRefreshApp.ps1
} -ArgumentList $server | Out-File -Append "C:\Temp\abc.txt"
```

Sub script:

```
"Came to sub script" | Out-File -Append "C:\Temp\abc.txt"
```

But this is not printing in outfile from subscript, please suggest.

Comment: The code you posted writes the job information as well as the line "Came to sub script" to the output file, as one would expect, so I'll hazard a guess that the code you posted here does *not* match your *actual* code.

Comment: `ScriptBlock` is for code, you should use `FilePath` to start a script: `Start-Job -FilePath "C:\Temp\EMEAProductRefreshApp.ps1" -ArgumentList $server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background job is killed when the parent exits, you should wait for the completion using Wait-Job:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { C:\Temp\EMEAProductRefreshApp.ps1 } -ArgumentList $server | Wait-Job | Out-File -Append "C:\Temp\abc.txt"
```